# Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AnnotationException mappedBy reference

Tags: hibernate, mapping

Can anyone help me with this problem please? I get this error below:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: model.entities.Project.Responsible in model.entities.User.projects
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:668)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1636)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1390)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.generateDropSchemaScript(Configuration.java:941)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.<init>(SchemaExport.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.<init>(SchemaExport.java:156)
    at model.dao.ProjectTest.schema(ProjectTest.java:21)
    at model.dao.ProjectTest.main(ProjectTest.java:56)
```

I tried all the solutions published in forums in vain. My entities are:

```
package model.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.*;



  @Entity
  @Table(name="users")
  public class User implements Serializable{




       /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 3044688521472776233L;
        int id_user;
        public String firstname;
        public String lastname;
        public String login;
        public String password;
        public String service_line;

        /**************/
        @Transient 
        public Set<Project> projects;

        /**************/
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "id_user")
        public int getId_user() {
            return id_user;
        }

        @Column(name = "firstname")
        public String getFirstname() {
            return firstname;
        }
        public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
            this.firstname = firstname;
        }


        @Column(name = "lastname")
        public String getLastname() {
            return lastname;
        }
        public void setLastname(String lastname) {
            this.lastname = lastname;
        }

        @Column(name = "login")
        public String getLogin() {
            return login;
        }
        public void setLogin(String login) {
            this.login = login;
        }

        @Column(name = "password")
        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }
        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        @Column(name = "service_line")
        public String getService_line() {
            return service_line;
        }
        public void setService_line(String service_line) {
            this.service_line = service_line;
        }



        /*****************/
        @OneToMany(mappedBy="responsible")  
        public Set<Project> getProjects()  
        {  
            return projects;  
        }  
        public void setProjects(Set<Project> projects)  
        {  
            this.projects = projects;  
        }  

    }

    package model.entities;

    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.sql.Date;
    import java.util.Set;

    import javax.persistence.*;


    @Entity
    @Table(name = "project")
    public class Project implements Serializable{


    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 974608598281873370L;

    int id_project;

    public String  name;

    public String type;

    public String project_EM;

    public String phase;

    public int sub_project;

    public String service_model;

    public String project_status;

    public String standby_status_explanation;

    public String nb_fte;

    public boolean monitoring_exemption;

    public int declines;

    public Date decline_date;

    /************/
    @Transient
    private User responsible;

    /*****************/

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id_project")
    public int getId_project() {
    return id_project;
}

@Column(name = "project_name")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
@Column(name = "project_type")
public String getType() {
    return type;
}
public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}
@Column(name = "project_EM")
public String getProject_EM() {
    return project_EM;
}
public void setProject_EM(String project_EM) {
    this.project_EM = project_EM;
}
@Column(name = "phase")
public String getPhase() {
    return phase;
}
public void setPhase(String phase) {
    this.phase = phase;
}
@Column(name = "nbr_sub_project")
public int getSub_project() {
    return sub_project;
}
public void setSub_project(int sub_project) {
    this.sub_project = sub_project;
}
@Column(name = "service_model")
public String getService_model() {
    return service_model;
}
public void setService_model(String service_model) {
    this.service_model = service_model;
}
@Column(name = "status")
public String getProject_status() {
    return project_status;
}
public void setProject_status(String project_status) {
    this.project_status = project_status;
}
@Column(name = "standby_status_explanation")
public String getStandby_status_explanation() {
    return standby_status_explanation;
}
public void setStandby_status_explanation(String standby_status_explanation) {
    this.standby_status_explanation = standby_status_explanation;
}

@Column(name = "nbr_fte")
public String getNb_fte() {
    return nb_fte;
}
public void setNb_fte(String nb_fte) {
    this.nb_fte = nb_fte;
}

@Column(name = "monitoring_exemption")
public boolean isMonitoring_exemption() {
    return monitoring_exemption;
}
public void setMonitoring_exemption(boolean monitoring_exemption) {
    this.monitoring_exemption = monitoring_exemption;
}

@Column(name = "declines")
public int getDeclines() {
    return declines;
}
public void setDeclines(int declines) {
    this.declines = declines;
}
@Column(name = "decline_date")
public Date getDecline_date() {
    return decline_date;
}
public void setDecline_date(Date decline_date) {
    this.decline_date = decline_date;
}

public Project()
{
    super();
}

public Project(String name,String type, String project_em,String phase,String status)
{
    this.name=name;
    this.type=type;

}
/*************/
 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)  
 @JoinColumn(name="id_user",referencedColumnName="id_user", nullable = false)
    public User getUser()  
    {  
        return responsible;  
    }  
    public void setUser(User responsible)  
    {  
        this.responsible =responsible;  
    }  

}

package model.dao;

import model.entities.Project;
import model.entities.User;

import org.hibernate.*;
import org.hibernate.cfg.*;
import org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport;

import util.HibernateUtil;

public class ProjectTest {

public static void schema()
{
    Configuration config= new Configuration();
    config.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);
    config.addAnnotatedClass(Project.class);

    config.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    new SchemaExport(config).create(true, true);;
}

public static void addProject(String name, String type, String EM, String phase, String model, String status) {

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    User user=new User();
    user.setFirstname("Maryam");
    user.setLastname("maryam");
    user.setLogin("ma");
    user.setPassword("ma");
    session.save(user);
    Project ar = new Project();

    ar.setName(name);
    ar.setType(type);
    ar.setProject_EM(EM);
    ar.setPhase(phase);
    ar.setService_model(model);
    ar.setProject_status(status);
    ar.setUser(user);
    user.getProjects().add(ar);




    session.save(ar);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    schema();
    addProject("a","b","nicolas","c","BASIC","execution");
}

}
```

The mapped reference "responsible" exists in Project entity and still don't know where the error is.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You configure that the mappedBy binding to the property responsible, but use a getter + setter with a differnet name which does probably created your issue. Rename the getter setter according to the standard -> getResponsible/setResponsible.

Beside that, is there a specific reason for this @Transient on the memeber (which is probably the reason hibernate does not find it) and @JoinColumn on the getter. I don't see the point in this. I would just put the ManyToOne on the field.

Comment: thank u for your response. I actually fixed the problem. I moved the annotaions to the attributes instead of methods .